# How can I download XML file to Document Directory of blackberry using programming?

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I have link of XML file, how I want to download it in my local directory as application starts,,,,

I am working on blackberry application

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
HttpConnection httpConnector = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(urlStr + ";interface=wifi");
httpConnector.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET);
InputStream in = httpConnector.openInputStream();

BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer();
String line;
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    content.append(line + "\n");
}
```

This code will work if device has wifi connection. Of course, you should use try-catch block and you can use String instead of StringBuffer, it is up to you.

Comment: A more reliable way is to you use the ConnectionFactory.getConnection() method, as this does not assume that a WIFI connection exists.

Comment: Oh I am sorry, I totally forgot that Blackberry does not support BufferedReader. I should share custom BufferedReader class. But it has 500 lines. I will try to provide a link for you.

Comment: Here it is:
http://dev.telnic.org/trac/browser/apps/blackberry/trunk/blackberry/src/org/not/java/io/BufferedReader.java